# How to print to screen after redirect print to file, in python?

Tags: python

I have a code use print() to write in file:

```
with open('test.xml', "w+") as outfile:
    sys.stdout = outfile
```

Now I want write to console after this code, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restore `sys.stdout` from [`sys.__stdout__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__):

```
with open('test.xml', "w+") as outfile:
    sys.stdout = outfile

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

or you could store the original up-front:

```
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
with open('test.xml', "w+") as outfile:
    sys.stdout = outfile

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
```

You could use a context manager here:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def redirect_stdout(filename):
    orig_stdout = sys.stdout
    try:
        with open(filename, "w+") as outfile:
            sys.stdout = outfile
            yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = orig_stdout
```

then use that in your code:

```
with redirect_stdout('test.xml'):
    # stdout is redirected in this block

# stdout is restored afterwards
```

Answer (score 1):

store stdout in a variable

```
stdout = sys.stdout
with open('test.xml', 'w+') as outfile:
    sys.stdout = outfile
    print("<text>Hello World</text>") # print to outfile instead of stdout

sys.stdout = stdout # now its back to normal
```

While this works really you should just be writing to the file directly

```
with open('test.xml', 'w+') as outfile
    outfile.write("<text>Hello World</text">)
```